# modify line content using python

Tags: python, sed, pyyaml

I have a requirement to modify a line in a YAML file using python code. The line I wanted to modify is the one that starts with `- {tokens`:

```
rpc: sync
nodes_dir: /data/tmp
list_provider:
- class_name: org.apache.test
  parameters:
  - {tokens: '{{ printf "%s/%s/%s/nodes" (env "var1") (env "var2") (env "var3") | key}}'}
```

I want to achieve this result:

```
rpc: sync
nodes_dir: /data/tmp
list_provider:
- class_name: org.apache.test
  parameters:
  - {tokens: ''}
```

I was using the YAML loader for python by it is not allowing the special characters in the file.

```
with open('test.yaml', 'r') as file:
    data = yaml.load(file)
print(data)
data["list_provider"][0]['parameters'][0]['tokens'] = str(list_var)
with open("test.yaml", "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(data, f)
```

I cannot use ruamel.yaml module as I cannot install new packages on my machine. How can I achieve this using PyYAML?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm testing your code using python 3.6.4 and pyyaml 3.12 with your sample yaml and the code you provided. I've replaced `list_var` with `''` because I don't know what goes there. I get the desired output? Am I testing with the wrong versions?

Comment: I am using python 2.7.13 and it doesn't work for this version

Comment: What message error do you got? Or, what is de difference between the desired and the actual result?

Comment: @brandizzi You get a `NameError: name 'list_var' is not defined` if you run that code.

Comment: Error message:

yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token found character '%' that cannot start any token in "/tmp/test.yaml", line 361, column 32

Comment: Value of list_var is null and is returned from an other function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i got your point correctly but i would go with pure python way:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'^ *- {tokens:.*}$')

modified_content = ''
with open('file.yaml', 'r') as fd:
    for line in fd.readlines():
        if r.match(line):
            line = re.sub(r'tokens:.*}$', "tokens: ''}", line)
        modified_content += line

with open('file.yaml', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(modified_content)
```

Comment: Your code assumes that YAML has not wrapped the token `'{{ printf ....}}'`, it could easily be dumped over multiple lines if that token gets longer.

Answer (score 0):

Your program almost gets you the output you need, you just need to change the `str(list_var)`, as that will throw an error, to `''`:

```
import sys
import yaml

with open('test.yaml', 'r') as file:
    data = yaml.load(file)
print(data)
data["list_provider"][0]['parameters'][0]['tokens'] = ''

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

outputs:

```
list_provider:
- class_name: org.apache.test
  parameters:
  - {tokens: ''}
nodes_dir: /data/tmp
rpc: sync
```

The key order, of the mapping at the root of the YAML document, is not preserved in PyYAML. But apart from that, this is exactly the output you requested.

Comment: I get the below error when I use the same code you posted. I am using python 2.7.13.


yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '%' that cannot start any token
  in "/tmp/test.yaml", line 361, column 32

Comment: @wasay You should not only use the code, but also the correct YAML file. Your YAML input doesn't have 361 lines, so you are testing with the incorrect `test.yaml` (alternatively you should post a **new** question that has the relevant part of that other `test.yaml`, line 361 and context, included).